# Inserting values into specific locations in a json file with Python

Tags: python, json, list, object, insert

Trying to find an elegant way to insert filenames from a `os.walk()` loop into a *specific* sub-element (for want of a better term) in a Python object that will be output as a JSON file.  If that does not make much sense, here are some visual output of what I've cobbled together so far.

code used:

```
import os
from os.path import normpath, basename
import json

ROOT_PATH = "sounds/"
jsonObject = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(ROOT_PATH):
   if files:
      elementId = basename(normpath(path)) + "Audio" # <-- builds custom Id based on path
      jsonObject.append( { "elementId" : elementId, "params" : { "audioPath" : path, "sounds" : [] } } )
      for name in files:
         jsonObject.append(name)  #  <-- problem lies here...

with open('sounds/Elements.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(jsonObject, outfile, indent=3, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
```

...which produces:

```
[
   {
      "elementId": "soundsAudio",
      "params": {
         "audioPath": "sounds/",
         "sounds": []
      }
   },
   "beep2.mp3",
   "heart_rate_flatline.mp3",
   "shhh.mp3",
   {
      "elementId": "aha_aedAudio",
      "params": {
         "audioPath": "sounds/aha_aed",
         "sounds": []
      }
   },
   "AnalyzingHeartRhythm.mp3",
   "AttachPadsToPatientsBareChest.mp3",
   "BeginCPR.mp3",
   "Charging.mp3",
   "DoNotTouchThePatient.mp3"
]
```

...and this is *really* close.  But I've run into a brain block getting the list of mp3 files *into* the `sounds` section, so that it looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "elementId": "soundsAudio",
      "params": {
         "audioPath": "sounds/",
         "sounds": [ "beep2.mp3",
                     "heart_rate_flatline.mp3",
                     "shhh.mp3"
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "elementId": "aha_aedAudio",
      "params": {
         "audioPath": "sounds/aha_aed",
         "sounds": [ "AnalyzingHeartRhythm.mp3",
                     "AttachPadsToPatientsBareChest.mp3",
                     "BeginCPR.mp3",
                     "Charging.mp3",
                     "DoNotTouchThePatient.mp3"
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

`.append`, `.extend`, and `.insert` are letting me down at this point (or maybe I'm not using them properly), and doing an overly complex regex search-n-replace-copy-n-paste operation for the `sounds` element feels...dirty somehow.

I realize I may be resigned to doing that anyway before outputting the whole thing into a JSON file.  Any thoughts, tips, or solution examples I can absorb would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "json object" - `json` is just a way to serialize / deserialize common data types (strings, nums, arrays and associative arrays).  All you have in your Python code are Python objects, in your case a list (named `JsonObject`) containing dicts which themselves contains lists and dicts, really nothing special to know here except plain basic Python datatypes.

Of course none of the list methods of your `jsonObject` list will be of any use here since the object you want to store your files list into is the dict you just appended to the list, not the list itself.

The solution is obvious: just add the files list to your element *before* (or when) you append it to your main list, ie:

```
if files:
    elementId = basename(normpath(path)) + "Audio" 
    element = { 
      "elementId" : elementId, 
      "params" : { 
         "audioPath" : path, 
         "sounds" : list(files)
         },
      }
    jsonObject.append(element)
```

or more simply:

```
if files:
    elementId = basename(normpath(path)) + "Audio" 
    jsonObject.append({ 
      "elementId" : elementId, 
      "params" : { 
         "audioPath" : path, 
         "sounds" : list(files)
         },
      })
```

Comment: For the record, I did write "...a Python object that will be output as a JSON file..."  but I can see how using jsonObject in the code was confusing.  Indeed I was mixing terms here with the bad choice of names.  Funny enough, I had 'jsonList' and at some point when tinkering I changed it to 'jsonObject' for some unknown reason.  Probably what got me thinking on a wrong track of using .append/.insert and so on.  Once I saw your use of list(), it became a "duh, of course that's what I need".  Thanks for the brain rattling, Bruno!

Comment: FWIW the call to `list(files)` is not even necessary in Python 2.x since it's already a `list` - but it might (or not) be another kind of iterable in Python 3.x and didn't want to waste time checking the docs...

Comment: Oh and yes, usually "json object" is the term used for the json representation of an associative array (basically a Python `dict` or a plain javascript `object`). In your code, once dumped to json what you'll have will be a list of "json objects" ;)

Comment: Understood.  In an earlier, flatter, version of the JSON output I used only the name of the list and it worked as advertised.  Obviously time for a break from the computer if I was getting stumped so easily.  Thanks again!  (I wonder if I should edit my question to change jsonObject to jsonList for clarity?)

Comment: question fixed to better reflect the content